# QUADRO SDI SDK helps to work on Gpu memory without Host memory?

Tags: cuda, sdi

I will have quadro 4000 with SDI IO cards and with this i want to process video camera output with gpu(cuda) but the main problem is; this is real time process so i don't want to send data to host memory because of latency i want to always process video camera output data on Gpu memory so question  is 
Is SDI Sdk is true way to do this job if yes Where should I start from?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an SDI video source, and a Quadro SDI capture card (along with a Quadro GPU) you should be able to capture the SDI video source frames directly onto the GPU memory on the Quadro GPU, using the [Quadro SDI SDK](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-digital-video-pipeline.html).

To get access to the Quadro SDI SDK, you should start by [filling out an application](https://registration.nvidia.com/SDI.aspx) to become a registered Quadro SDI developer.  Once you have access to the SDI SDK, read the documentation on how to capture incoming SDI video frames.

Once you have the frame capture mechanism working (through the Quadro SDI SDK) you should be able to use [CUDA graphics interop](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP) with DirectX (assuming you're not using Win8), or OpenGL, to make the frame(s) available to CUDA for processing.

There are a number of graphics interop [samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#graphics).